# Using Spearman correlation with Sklearn KNN for pattern matching

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, correlation

I am trying to use Spearman's correlation wrapped in a user defined metric to find nearest neighbors in Scikit-learn. For some reason it only works when the number of columns in my training data is 5 and k=5 as well. For any other combination(eg. no. of columns=8 and k=6) it would give me the following error. (Here train and test set has 4 columns and k=4). It works perfectly if I use Pearson's for correlation. Does anybody know why this can happen or how to fix it? Thank you.

```
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
def spearmancorr(x,y):
    rho, pval = spearmanr(x,y, axis=0)
    return rho * (-1)

from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=4, algorithm='ball_tree', metric=spearmancorr)
nbrs.fit(train)
dist, ind = nbrs.kneighbors(test)

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f04b508b1263> in <module>()
      5 for i in range(1):
      6     nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=4, algorithm='ball_tree', metric=spearmancorr)
----> 7     nbrs.fit(train)
      8     dist, ind = nbrs.kneighbors(test)
      9     print "for: " + funcs[i]

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
    797             or [n_samples, n_samples] if metric='precomputed'.
    798         """
--> 799         return self._fit(X)

C:\Users\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.pyc in _fit(self, X)
    238             self._tree = BallTree(X, self.leaf_size,
    239                                   metric=self.effective_metric_,
--> 240                                   **self.effective_metric_params_)
    241         elif self._fit_method == 'kd_tree':
    242             self._tree = KDTree(X, self.leaf_size,

SystemError: NULL result without error in PyObject_Call
```

Comment: Which version of sklearn are you using? I don't get such error with ver. 0.18.1

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an error occurred before sklearn 0.14.1. Try upgrade to the later version or the latest 0.18.1 one.

Refer to issues [#2878](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2878) and [#3032](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3032).

Comment: I am using the latest version of scikit-learn 0.18.1-4 its still not working